# UWP : Binding selected date in calendarview

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, bind

I want to do a two way bind from my ViewModel to selected date (single) in my XAML calendarview.
But we have no dependency properties to do it.

What to do ?

EDIT:
the code I tried but I got Error.
Its the combination of these two topics:
[How to use CalenderView in UWP MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258070/how-to-use-calenderview-in-uwp-mvvm)
[How to select rang of dates on finger slide on Calendar Control - UWP Win10 VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127597/how-to-select-rang-of-dates-on-finger-slide-on-calendar-control-uwp-win10-vs20)
XAML:

```
<CalendarView  MinHeight="250" MaxHeight="500" MaxWidth="720"   FontWeight="Normal" 
             DayItemFontWeight="Light" MinWidth="100"
                          SelectionMode="Single"
                          Style="{StaticResource Mahcalenderstyle}" Visibility="Visible" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="MyCalendarView" DisplayMode="Month" Margin="9,25,9,0"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedDatesChanged="CalendarView_SelectedDatesChanged"
             CalendarViewDayItemStyle="{StaticResource CalendarViewDayItemStyle1}"
                          />
```

And my VM:

```
 private DateTimeOffset _selecteddate;
    public DateTimeOffset SelectedDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _selecteddate;

        }
        set
        {

            if (_selecteddate != value)
            {
                _selecteddate = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this,
                        new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedDate"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public CalendarViewModel()
    {

        SelectedDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;}
```

The helper:

```
 public static class CalendarViewHelper
{
    public static IList<DateTimeOffset> GetSelectedDates(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (IList<DateTimeOffset>)obj.GetValue(SelectedDatesProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectedDates(DependencyObject obj, IList<DateTimeOffset> value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedDatesProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDatesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedDates", typeof(IList<DateTimeOffset>), typeof(CalendarView),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) =>
            {
                var cv = d as CalendarView;
                var dates = e.NewValue as IList<DateTimeOffset>;

                if (cv != null && dates != null)
                {
                    foreach (var date in dates)
                    {
                        cv.SelectedDates.Add(date);
                    }
                }
            }));

}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: @NoorAShuvo Nothind that special. I found nothing :(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258070/how-to-use-calenderview-in-uwp-mvvm
I did it but did not work

Comment: Please share the code you tried or you won't get much help.

Comment: @Alex Added some of the code :)

Comment: Any reason that you can't use a CalendarDatePicker?  That has a SelectedDate property that can be bound to.

Comment: @MarkW Yes there is. My app just needs a Calendarview :(

Comment: @Mohsen Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258070/how-to-use-calenderview-in-uwp-mvvm

Comment: I can't find where you have used `SelectedDate` in your xaml.

Comment: @JustinXL There is no DependencyProperty for that. So we can not declare it from XAML. But we can do it in C# code behind

Comment: @JustinXL I did it by an attached property, but it failed :|

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use CalenderView in UWP MVVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258070/how-to-use-calenderview-in-uwp-mvvm)

Comment: @Archana HAHAHAHA you are wrong.

Comment: Answer given is same. Please cross verify again

Comment: @Archana There is some differences. And for VM I should use compiled binding

Comment: Answer given by Justin XL uses compiled binding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an attached property of a `DateTimeOffset`, not an `IList<DateTimeOffset>` since you only want to select **one** date.

So instead of the code you copied over from my other answer, you will need something like this -

```
public static class CalendarViewHelper
{
    public static DateTimeOffset GetSelectedDate(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (DateTimeOffset)obj.GetValue(SelectedDateProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectedDate(DependencyObject obj, DateTimeOffset value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedDate", typeof(DateTimeOffset), typeof(CalendarView),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) =>
            {
                var cv = (CalendarView)d;
                var date = (DateTimeOffset)e.NewValue;

                cv.SelectedDates.Clear();
                cv.SelectedDates.Add(date);
            }));
}
```

Note you will need to call `Clear` to clear all the previously selected date(s) because the `SelectionMode` is set to `Single`, without doing so, an error will be thrown.

Then you will just need to hook it up in xaml with your `SelectedDate` property.

```
<CalendarView SelectionMode="Single"
                  DisplayMode="Month"
                  local:CalendarViewHelper.SelectedDate="{x:Bind SelectedDate, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: Hey, I got the same error as before in this.InitializeComponent(); Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The text associated with this error code could not be found.



Failed to assign to property 'Denna.Classes.CalendarViewHelper.SelectedDate'. [Line: 60 Position: 58]'

Comment: I donno why when I x:bind from local property it does fine, but when I use binding from my VM it goes into issue :(

Comment: Put your code in a sample project n send me the link.

Comment: FIWED. Thank you.

Comment: Cool so you figured it out! :)

Comment: I had to use x:bind to my VM instead if that binding :|